# Timeout with bind, call & apply methods

Tags: javascript, closures, this, settimeout, iife

Up until now, I've always used `var self = this` before creating a function that would need access to its parent. However the `bind()` method seems like a more appropriate way to do so and I'm exploring that option, along with the `apply()` and `call()` methods.

This is what I came up with to compare all three:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fho1t5f8/)

```js
(function(){

    this.say = function(text){
        
        console.log(text);
    }
        
    this.run = function(){
        
        console.clear();
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.say('bind');
        }.bind(this), 1000);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.say('call');
        }.call(this), 1000);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.say('apply');
        }.apply(this), 1000);
    }
    
    this.run();
    
})();
```

But the script leaves me with some questions:

1. Why don't the `call()` and `apply()` methods respect the timeout like the `bind()` method does and which one should I use?
2. Is there any difference between the following syntaxes which behave similarly:

   ```
   setTimeout( function(){ this.say('bind'); }.bind(this) , 1000);

   setTimeout( (function(){ this.say('bind'); }).bind(this) , 1000);

   setTimeout( (function(){ this.say('bind'); }.bind(this)) , 1000);
   ```

Comment: `.call` and `.apply` do not work the same way that `.bind` does. They invoke the function immediately.

Comment: Agree with @JesseKernaghan. `call` and `apply` invokes the function while `bind` only binds the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a key point here (but the key point is very obfuscated in documentation).

You know whenever you write a function like this:

```
function something() {
    // ... whatever
}
```

It's just a function reference sitting there by itself. It hasn't been called yet.

When you write something like this:

```
(function something() {

})()
```

Or this:

```
function something() { ... }

something();
```

You've now ***called*** the function. Those are two very completely different concepts.

In the first one where the function is just sitting there without having been called, it's referred to as a **function reference**, and that's exactly what `.bind` returns: **a function reference**.

`.call` and `.apply` return the ***return value*** of whatever function, in the new context. So in fake JavaScript la-la land, it would look something like this:

```
function() {

}.bind(this)

// returns a function reference: function() {  }
```

Whereas:

```
function() {
    return 'hello';
}.call(this)
// returns hello... NOT A FUNCTION REFERENCE!
```

## You see...

You would probably never do something like this:

```
function hello() {
    return true;
}

setTimeout(hello(), 100);
```

You'd get an error: `setTimeout expected a Function, and it received a Boolean`, or something like that.

[image: function]
[image: error]

^ That's not a very semantic error, but it's an error nonetheless.

But, what you **would** do is something like this:

```
function hello() {
    return true;
}

setTimeout(hello, 100);
```

See the difference? That last example is okay, **because you passed in a function reference**.

Because internally, `setTimeout` does something like this:

```
window.setTimeout = function(callback) {
    // a bunch of other stuff, and...

    callback();
};
```

## As far as your second question goes...

Those are pretty much all equivalent. Closures make sense though whenever you're declaring variables that you don't want to give other objects access to.

To help you understand closures a little bit, let's pretend we're not even talking about JavaScript.

In math, you know how you can do something like `a + b * c`?

Well, when you group them by parentheses, it kind of changes the behavior: `(a + b) * c`.

Now, obviously that's not quite related to JavaScript in the sense that in JavaScript we're not worried about order of operations (unless you're actually doing math in JavaScript), but the whole idea is that those parentheses just act as a **container** (what we call a closure) for whatever is inside of it.

So when you put a function inside parentheses, you're just hiding that function from the outside world, but it can still return stuff, and it can still have access to parent scopes (like `window`, for example).

## A cool example:

```
var name = (function(name) {
    return name
})(function() {
    return 'Jane';
}());

console.log(name); // => Jane
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `.call` and `.apply` execute the functions on which they are called immediately. What this means is that in those cases you are passing the *result* of `call` or `apply` on your anonymous function to `setTimeout` and that result is `undefined` because those functions don't return anything.

`bind` on the other hand returns a new function, which you are then correctly passing to `setTimeout`. To get call and apply to behave similarly,  move them inside the anonymous function:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.say.call (this, 'call');
    }, 1000);
```

for example.

2. Afaik those are equivalent.